# How do I create menu link icons?

Tags: routes, media, 7

I noticed that when I added a new menu link, an icon is now show like groups, events, etc. How do I add an icon for that menu link item?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [menu icons](https://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) module to generate icon for the menu item.

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's
>   configuration form.
>
> After uploading the image, the icon data will be added to the menu
>   link's options array.
>
> When a menu link is goes through the theme layer, it will receive an
>   extra class which by default is used to attach the images as a
>   background image to the corresponding menu item.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into a similar issue. I have a bootstrap based theme that comes with FontAwesome icons, so I was hoping to be able to directly use these icons in my menu title without installing a separate module.

For example `<i>fa-home</i>Home` as the menu title would display the home icon before the title "Home", or `<i>fa-user</i>` would  only show the user icon without any text. 
For that I wrote the following theming function:

```
function MY_THEME_menu_link($variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  $pattern = '/(^<i>)([a-z\-]+)(<\/i>)([\w\s]*)/i';
  if (preg_match($pattern, $element['#title'], $matches) > 0) {
    $element['#title'] = preg_replace($pattern, '<span class="icon"><i class="'. $matches[2] .'"></i></span> ' . $matches[4], $element['#title']);
    $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
  }
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

If you want to do the same with superfish menus, you need to add a different theming function, since superfish menus do not call theme_menu_link:

```
function scholarly_lite_superfish_menu_item_link(array $variables) {
  $menu_title = $variables['menu_item']['link']['title'];
  $menu_path = $variables['menu_item']['link']['link_path'];
  $link_options = $variables['link_options'];

  $pattern = '/(^<i>)([a-z\-]+)(<\/i>)([\w\s]*)/i';
  if (preg_match($pattern, $menu_title, $matches) > 0) {
    $menu_title = preg_replace($pattern, '<span class="icon"><i class="'. $matches[2] .'"></i></span> ' . $matches[4], $menu_title);
    $link_options = $variables['link_options'] + array('html' => TRUE);
    // need to pass title without markup to page
  }
  return l($menu_title, $menu_path, $link_options);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else stumbling upon similar configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In your template.php file place this

```
<?php
function phptemplate_menu_item($mid, $children = '', $leaf = TRUE) {
  $link = menu_item_link($mid);
  $css_id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', strip_tags($link)));
  return '<li id="' . $css_id . '" class="' . ($leaf ? 'leaf' : ($children ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed')) .'">'. $link . $children ."</li>\n";
}
?>
```

It'll assign a unique id to each of your menu items, allowing you to attach css to individual menu items. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these module to add icon in menu

[Menuimage](https://www.drupal.org/project/menuimage)

> When editing a menu link, this module provides a file field to upload
>   an image to associate with a menu item. In the array returned by
>   menu_link_load, the fid of the image file is contained in
>   [options][content][image]. This may may be passed as a parameter to
>   file_load to obtain its public:// uri, and further used with either
>   file_build_uri or image_style_url to populate the src= attribute of an
>   .

[Menu_icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_icons)

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's
>   configuration form.
>
> After uploading the image, the icon data will be added to the menu
>   link's options array.